# How to run real phoenix server during test?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

I'm implementing kinda tricky functionality with external libraries I can't mock. They needs to implement real requests to the server. So,

how can I run a web-server during tests implementation?

P.S. My `config/test.exs`:

```
config :my_reelty, MyReelty.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url:  [host: "localhost", port: 5000] # Specific port
```

I'm trying to `curl http://localhost:5000` but getting `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused`

Comment: You want to run your Phoenix app on port 5000 while you run the tests for the same app? Sorry, I'm not following what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yes, I want to run app on port 5000 to run tests

Comment: Do you have `config :my_reelty, MyReelty.Endpoint, server: true` in `config/test.exs`? If not, try adding that. I can access the server from my tests with `server: true`.

Comment: Excellent, please make it answer

Comment: @asiniy, i trying to something that sounds similar to the title of your question. can you explain a little more how you did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `server: true` to the `Endpoint`'s config:

```
config :my_reelty, MyReelty.Endpoint, server: true
```

The `phoenix.new` may have already generated similar config with `server: false` (it does for me in v1.2.0), so you can just change that `false` to `true`.